# Using condition from one column to create new grouping variable

Tags: r, grouping, subset

I have a long data frame:

```
Group| Variable  |   Value  | 

0       A_pre          20            
1       B_post         19                
2       B_pre          30                
1       B_pre          25                
2       A_post         32              
0       B_pre          NA                
0       A_pre          19                
1       B_pre          20               
2       B_post         20
0       B_pre          30
```

I would like to split the data frame using the terms "pre" and "post" to create a new grouping variable "phase" to look like this:

```
Group| variable  | Phase  |  Value | 

0       A          pre        20        
1       B          post       19        
2       B          pre        30        
1       B          pre        25        
2       A          post       32        
0       B          pre        NA        
0       A          pre        19        
1       B          pre        20        
2       B          post       20        
0       B          pre        30
```

I have tried

```
example <- subset(df_long, variable = select(ends_with("pre") & select(ends_with("post"))))
```

and also

```
example2 <- subset(df_long, variable == "A_post" & variable == "A_pre")
```

The closest I have come is:

```
example4 <- df_long %>% 
  mutate(variable = paste0(substring(df_long$variable, 1, 1), ".", substring(df_long$variable, 2))) %>% 
separate(varible, into = c("test", "phase"), remove = FALSE)
```

but I am missing something.

Comment: You are over-complicating. `df_long %>% separate(Variable, into = c("variable", "phase"))` should work.

Comment: Apologies, total newbie here. Spent 2 hours on this. Thank you

Comment: No apologies necessary!